# How does unity leveling work/show in mh3U?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

My friend and I play multiplayer for the 3DS from time to time. I finished the story and killed Dire Miralis and he just got to high rank. when we do quests we get unity and we are both level 3, it shows on my guild card but on his it still says level 0 with all of the stickers, does he need to get further in the game to see his unity level up or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

Unity increases when you play with people whose Guild Card you have accepted. From your Guild Card list, you can only check how much unity **you** have gained from playing with a certain player, not that player's total unity. If your friend's unity isn't increasing, it's because you have not sent him your Guild Card.

Comment: I have accepted his guild card, the guild card list says his unity level is level 3 but when he checks his own guild card or when i check it it says his unity is level 0 with all stickers on the card.

Comment: @wrigglenite is saying that HE needs to accept YOUR guild card for him to receive unity.

Comment: Oh ok thank you i'll check next time i see him and make sure we do that, thank you.